# View Woocommerce data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this code to try and get products and categories from woocommerce

```
function get_me_list_of($atts, $content = null)
{   
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => $atts[0], 'orderby' => 'rand' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo '<h1 class="upp">Style '.$atts[0].'</h1>';
    echo "<ul class='mylisting'>";
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 

    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'thumbnail').'</a></li>';

    endwhile; 

    echo "</ul>";

    wp_reset_query(); 

}
```

I put this in a file and named it "template-prods.php" in the wordpress theme being used. I then created a new page and used the Template "prods". But nothing shows up on the page.

Is there something wrong with the code or is it the way I tried to view the data (ie creating an template and using it in a new page)?

Comment: functions go in functions.php, you then access those functions in template files.

Comment: Ok but then how would I call the function from the template? Do I simply use `<?php get_me_list_of(); ?>` i the template and it would show on the page?

Comment: Correct :) you can then use your functions in template files